# Powershell Send-MailMessage Attachments Test if File Exists else change $body

Tags: powershell

I am using a `Send-MailMessage` function to email the log files of a backup. I have edited the PowerShell profile so a transcript file is automatically created. If the backup encounters an error the SendMailErr function is called.

This works but I would like to add the transcript file and log file as an attachment (if they exist). If they don't exist I would like to change the body of the email to say "Transcript does not exist etc."

My clumsy code in it's current state

```
# Mail Settings
$to = "first.lastname@unisa.edu.au"
$from = "$env:ComputerName@unisa.edu.au"
$Smtp = "mx-out.company.edu.au"
$body = "Please review attached log file $seperator See $blog for WBAdmin Log"
$attachments = "$logfile","$trans" | Where-Object {Test-Path $_ }

#Transcript File
$trans = Get-ChildItem $bLog ` 
  -filter "$env:computername-PSTranscript-$(get-date -format ddMMyyyy).log" 
  -Name

function SendMailErr { 
$MessageParameters = @{
    From = $from
    To = $to
    Subject = "ALERT: Backup Failed for $env:ComputerName.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN `
                     - $((Get-Date).ToShortDateString())"
    Body = $body      
    SmtpServer = $Smtp
    Priority = "High"
    Attachments = $attachments
}
Send-MailMessage @MessageParameters 
Exit
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Amelia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually approach that like this:
Start with an empty array for $body.  As you encounter conditions that you want to add text about to the body, add those strings using +=.  Before you send it, run it through out-string to convert it to a string and add newlines.

```
$body = @()

 if (test-path $logfile){$body += "Log file $logfile attached"}
     else {$body += "Log file $logfile was not found"}

 if (test-path $trans){$body += "Transcript file $trans attached"}
     else {$body += "Transcript file $trans was not found"}

 $body = $body | out-string
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response :) If I had 2 Send-MailMessage Functions, 1 for backup success and 1 for backup fail, is there a way to just have 1 fuction but pass particular parameters based on success/fail?
The Success MailMessage function params are different for $subject, $attachments (just $logfile) and $body. It also doesn't exit the script
Thanks

Comment: The easiest way to do that is create 2 hash tables with the parameters for each situation (
S

Comment: Create two hash tables of the parameters specific to each outcome, pass that hash table to the function as a parameter, and then within your fuction splat that to send-mailmessage.

Comment: Or you could use parameter sets: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878348%28v=vs.85%29.aspx This allows you to you use your function in different situations. But what seems to be the best solution for you is adding a switch parameter

Comment: You could use the switch to decide which set of parameters to use, but I'd still use the hash tables for the parameters, and use the switch to decide which one to splat.  Might consider using a Data section and convertfrom-stringdata to populate the hash tables.  That gets volatile specifics like recipient lists and smtp servers out of the code section and makes it easy to have the emails in different lantuages if you need that.